# XMLStarlet isn't deleting elements

Tags: xml, bash, xpath, xml-namespaces, xmlstarlet

Currently I have the following commandline with $f representing the file:

```
xmlstarlet ed -d "//*/packageVersions" $f;
```

I've also tried

```
xmlstarlet ed -d "//packageVersions" $f;
```

I'm trying to parse xml files that contains different root element names, this is the example below its ApexClass:

```
<ApexClass xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>38.0</apiVersion>
    <packageVersions>
        <majorNumber>2</majorNumber>
        <minorNumber>2003</minorNumber>
        <namespace>abc</namespace>
    </packageVersions>
    <packageVersions>
        <majorNumber>2</majorNumber>
        <minorNumber>2001</minorNumber>
        <namespace>def</namespace>
    </packageVersions>
    <status>Active</status>
</ApexClass>
```

However after running the script, I see in the console the content of the file but the file hasn't changed.

Any thoughts to what i'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of the default namespace `http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata`.

Try binding that to a prefix and using it in the XPath.

Example (untested)...

```
xmlstarlet ed -N x="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" -d "//x:packageVersions" $f;
```

See http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch05s01.html for more info.

If the XML files might have different namespaces, but the element is always `packageVersions` (with or without a namespace prefix), you can resort to testing the local name...

```
xmlstarlet ed -d "//*[local-name()='packageVersions']" $f;
```

Comment: thank you Daniel! I had tried that before but never with the -N which what was missing. However while the console output is correct. The file is still unchanged. I've tried $f > $f but that just leads to a empty file.

Comment: @DimlyAware - Try adding `-L` which will edit the file inplace. (You can do `xmlstarlet ed --help` to see possible options.)

Comment: Thank you that worked! I tried the --help but i still couldn't figured it out.

Comment: Glad I could help!